# How to make a div 100% width minus a certain amount?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, web

So I have a div that I want to be:

100% width (of viewport) - 150px

How would I show this in CSS or Javascript?

Comment: This is one thing CSS has left along entirely, which IMO is a Very Bad Thing. Mozilla browsers have an `eval()` operator (can't find the docs) which does what you want, although I'm not sure it does percentages as these are calculated when the page is rendered.

Comment: Do you know of any work arounds, or anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Container of your div must be `position:relative` (or absolute...but not default), and div style must be like this:

```
position:relative;
width:auto;
margin:0px 150px 0px 0px;
```

Comment: What I actually ended up doing was `position:relative;width:auto;margin-left:150px(give or take a few pixels); but you got me on the right track` :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery $(window) selector to get the viewport width and change the width of the div you want

```
  var width = $(window).width();
  $("div").css("width", width-150);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to go look up the CSS style

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Normally, the 100% is calculated for the size of the insides, which is utterly useless if your box contains any sort of padding or border whatsoever. With box-sizing, it is calculated for the outside of the border to be that size. Incredibly useful for making % sized divs with non-zero padding and border line up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Heres everything put together...

http://toomanyprojects.weare88.com/uploads/fixed-col-fluid-col/